# Wi-Fi disabled by hardware switch

Tags: wireless

I just installed my first Ubuntu OS on my Lenovo G50-30 Laptop . Everything runs smoothly except the Wi-Fi . I tried looking for the fix on the web but nothing works for me, i keep getting the same result Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch.

Comment: Hardware switch also applies to some keyboard combination. Mine is for example <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. You should have that, too.

Answer (score 2):

A quick review of the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1397021) for this issue found patched binaries made available by pilot6 that resolve this problem [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07642x3lziqgmz9/AACL0AF-Ck6kL0w6x4LlGd-Ra/stable/3.16.0-33.44?dl=0) I can't expand further as I have neither the hardware nor the dropbox account required. The solution was tested and confirmed by @Mitch who could likely do a better job of filling in the blanks.

I can confirm that the patch works perfectly.  I have a Lenovo G50-30 laptop, that I installed the patch on.  If for some reason you can't get the patch from the above link, you can also download it from [here](https://copy.com/kvkRmACXHJMKxh2c).

Its in the form of a zip file, and once you download it, more likely to the downloads folder, go ahead, and right click on it, and choose Extract Here.  What that will do is create a new folder called 3.16.0-33.44 inside the Downloads folder, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where you un-zipped the file, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Once the installation is done, go ahead, and reboot.

I have rebooted multiple times, and ran an update, and everything works the way it should.

Comment: @Mitch Feel free to fill in any detail that would be helpful here. I would if I could.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I do not have the laptop in question, so I can't test it. But it seems a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1397021); it is said to work after the workaround:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: I happen to have the same laptop, and the same problem.  It works until the next reboot.

Comment: @Mitch sounds like a candidate for a startup script. ;-D

Comment: @ElderGeek yes it does, but I'm looking for a solution, not a workaround, if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Mitch in the launchpad bug there is a kernel patch ;-) --- a solution, although well... you have to be patient to see it in official kernels.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1397021

Comment: binaries here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07642x3lziqgmz9/AACGWNO5_lNnX7x7tYMoH9gka?dl=0

Comment: @ElderGeek I'm running 14.04.2 with kernel 3.16.0-33.44, I don't think that dropping to a previous version would do the trick, would it?

Comment: @Mitch as I don't have the hardware to test with I can neither confirm nor deny. I would try it and learn something in the process if I did.

Comment: @ElderGeek I tried [This](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/07642x3lziqgmz9/AAA59KZ8xMY-57ZvPCu5J1aHa/next/3.16.0-33.44?dl=0),and can confirm that it works perfectly.  Go ahead and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a ppa with the patched ideapad-laptop. To install it do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop
```

**Update** For those who uses kernel 3.19 this ppa can be removed since 3.19.0-26 kernel includes this patch.